# Why is the text in the textfields of my form grey?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I'm writing a rails app and in one of my views, I have a signup form. I'm using a bootstrap theme and in the textfields, when something is typed in, it is grey and hard to read. Without the theme the text is black and looks fine.

I've tried to edit the colors in the textarea classes of the theme but that hasn't worked.

What do I need to change to make the text a different color?

Comment: What theme specifically are you using? Also, if you could show a sample of the related html/css, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to apply a css style to the textfield to make the text black. Try something like...

`input {
  color:black;
}`

Put that code in a css file in your assets/css directory. Make sure this css is getting loaded after bootstrap so that it overwrites it. I find Google Chrome's inspector tool handy for see what styles are being applied.

Comment: thank you very much. I just changed the color attribute in the input class of the themes file

Comment: I'd recommend leaving the theme file alone and adding this code to a new css file, in case you want to upgrade the theme later, and to more easily see what you've changed. But, as always, whatever works, works!

Comment: Agree with Kenny.  Change the theme and you'll never be able to get updates, fixes or enhancements.  Over-write the setting with the 'load it after the bootstrap css' approach.